# Loading different files with $readmemh to the same memory in a automated loop?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm generating frames from a video file, which I then read from my testbench.
What I'm doing so far is to load the same memory "*mem*" with different memory image file every time the task is called, which works perfectly fine:

```
task play_frame(input [31:0] total_pixels, input [12:0] pic_num);  
begin
    @(posedge clk);
    case (pic_num)
        0: $readmemh("img_data/1920x1080/video_frame_1.mem", mem); 
        1: $readmemh("img_data/1920x1080/video_frame_2.mem", mem); 
        2: $readmemh("img_data/1920x1080/video_frame_3.mem", mem);
        ...
        ...
        ...

    endcase

    repeat (total_pixels) begin
        .
        .
        .
    end
    end
endtask
```

Now the problem is that I want to call this task 1000 times. Which means that I have to write down for each case the name of the file that I want to load into the memory mem_s.

Is there a way to automate this?

Maybe something like:

```
task play_frame(input [31:0] total_pixels, input [12:0] pic_num);  
begin
    @(posedge clk);
     $readmemh("img_data/1920x1080/video_frame_*$(pic_num)*.mem", mem);

    repeat (total_pixels) begin
        .
        .
        .
    end
    end
endtask
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $sformatf

```
 $readmemh($sformatf("img_data/1920x1080/video_frame_%0d.mem",pic_num), mem);
```